# LibGDX ShapeRenderer rotated

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering, map-editor

I'm having a weird problem with the LibGDX ShapeRenderer where it draws everything rotated.
Here are some images to show you what i mean:

This is what it looks like in Tiled(Map Editor):
[image: Tiled view]

This is how it looks like in game:

[image: ingame render]

As you can see, its rotated.

Heres the Code i use to render the mapobjects:

```
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    for (RectangleMapObject o : MovementSystem.objects.getByType(RectangleMapObject.class)) {
        Rectangle rect = o.getRectangle();
        shapeRenderer.rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.height, rect.width);
    }

    shapeRenderer.end();
```

The rectangle is positioned at the right place and it is definitely NOT rotated!
I checked this with a small collision detection test where i moved another rectangle over this one.
So it just gets drawn like this and i have no idea why^^
Would be nice if anybody could help me :)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swapping the width and height in ShapeRenderer.rect should fix the problem, see [the documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html#rect-float-float-float-float-).

Comment: hm yea that should work but why does it draw the rectangle rotated anyway? :/ Anyway thanks for the answer :)

Comment: `rect` expects first the width, then the height of the rectangle. You pass them the other way around. Is that intentional?

Comment: okay, didn't see that sorry xD